# NameError: global name 'getAllElements' is not defined when calling a class function

Tags: python, class, instance, nameerror

I'm probably overlooking something, but I got a class "parse" with a function "getAllElements". In the main script I import parse using

```
from parseXML import parse.
```

Then I do

```
parse = parse(file)
```

which works fine. But when I do

```
print parseXML.parse(file).getAllElements()
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'getAllElements' is not defined
```

Below is the code. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: changed the code after comment

```
class parse:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, file):
        # parse the xml file into a tree
        tree = xml.parse('/homes/ndeklein/test.featureXML')
        # Get the root node of the xml file
        self.rootElement = tree.getroot()
        # Set self.parent to rootElement, because the first element won't have a parent (because it is the root)
        self.parent = 'rootElement'
        # dictionary that contains the parent -> child relation
        self.parentChildDict = {}

    # Go recursively through all the elements in the xml file, starting at the choosen rootElement, until only leaves (elements that don't contain elements) are left
    # Return all the elements from the xml file
    def getAllElements(self):
        # if this is the first time this parent is seen:
        #     make elementDict with parent as key and child as value in a list
        if not self.parentChildDict.has_key(self.parent):
            self.parentChildDict[self.parent] = [self.rootElement]
        # else: add the child to the parent dictionary
        else:
            self.parentChildDict[self.parent].append(self.rootElement)
        for node in self.rootElement:
            # if the len of rootElement > 0 (there are more elements in the element):
            #    set self.parent to be node and recursively call getAllElements
            if len(self.rootElement) > 0:
                self.parent = node
                getAllElements()
        return self.parentChildDict
```

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# author: ndeklein
# date: 08/02/2012
# function: calls out the script

import parseXML
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml
import sys

#Parse XML directly from the file path
file = '/homes/ndeklein/EP-B1.featureXML'
# parse the xml file into a tree
print parseXML.parse(file).getAllElements()
```

Comment: Looking at the code quickly, there are multiple issues ... For starters the `class` definition syntax is not correct, `getAllElements` has syntax errors (`parent` instead of `self.parent` , etc. Please go over the code and fix it and try again with proper imports.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the class definition, removed the parts that I'm not using and got all the syntax errors out that I could find, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Nope, the code still has issues. Take a close look at  `getAllElements()` in the penultimate line. Does that look right to you? It needs to be `self.getAllElements()` which BTW is what is causing your name error. But there are still logical errors in the code. What are you doing with the returned value? It's just throwing it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your import and style of call, as Praveen alluded to.

Because you import in this fashion:

```
from foo import bar
```

You don't need to (and in fact shouldn't) explicitly declare foo in your call.

```
bar.baz()
```

Not

```
foo.bar.baz()
```

So in your case try the call:

```
parse(file).getAllElements()
```

But you still need to address the naked call in your recursion:
getAllElements() probably should be self.getAllElements()

Comment: doing it that way gives the same problem

Comment: doing self.getAllElements() gives me about 700 times: File "/homes/ndeklein/workspace/MS/src/parseXML.py", line 72, in getAllElements
    self.getAllElements()

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `parseXML` is not in your local namespace, because you're doing `from parseXML import parse`. Did you try importing `parseXML` directly and doing this instead?

```
import parseXML 
parseXML.parse(file).getAllElements()
```

You're getting NameError because you can't just call `getAllElements()` inside the method. It needs to be `self.getAllElements()`.

As mentioned in the comments, there are other logical errors in the code that you will need to correct.

Comment: That was what I had at first, but that doesn't work either. Gives the same problem